# Installing ubuntu while retaining Windows 8 recovery option

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, partitioning, installation

I have a problem with retaining the option to recover Windows 8 on a laptop, Acer Aspire E1. On my own laptop I have Win7 and had a partition called Windows recovery partition and I just left it there in case I needed to switch back sometimes. I just can't figure out how to do it on this laptop since there is no partition called recovery or anything similar.
The reason I want to do this is because I want to install ubuntu on this laptop but I want to have the option to switch back in case I needed to.

In the disk management it says there is one disk, Disk 0, and it is split into 4 parts:

1. In brackets it says it's a recovery partition, however it has 400mb free from 400mb, so it's absolutely empty
2. This one says system partition EFI and it's also empty 300mb free from 300mb
3. The third one is the partition (C:) it contains 448.19gb of space, so most of the disk
4. The fourth again says it's a recovery partition. However, it also says it's completely empty, 16.76gb free from 16.76gb

Making a recovery DVD won't help, since it only accesses the files from the disk, so I'd appreciate some guiding.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You say "retaining" windows recovery option, but it doesn't sound like you currently HAVE that option since all your recovery drives are blank. Perhaps your question is actually how to setup a Windows 8 Recovery Partition? These are usually created by tools specific to the OEM...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain why your recovery partitions are empty, but the reason for two of them is that one is a boot partition for the recovery software, while the other holds the files that will be restored during recovery.

Sometimes the recovery files are split between two partitions, with the Microsoft files in one and the manufacturer's driver and utility files in the other.

Since you seem to have lost the recovery partitions, I recommend that you obtain an install disc: it would be best if you can obtain one from the manufacturer, as they will also supply their drivers and utilities, but if not you can download it from Microsoft (though it will be 8.1 now), and all the manufacturer's files should be in their on-line support pages.

Reinstalling from an installation disc will give you more flexibility over where you install and what you keep, whereas the in-built recovery partition will normally restore the machine to its delivered state, keeping nothing. 
An alternative is to copy your existing disc to external media, which will allow you to recover to your machine's present.

Having said all that, I would recommend you shrink your current Windows partition to around 100GB or less, allowing you plenty of space to install Ubuntu as a second boot, while retaining the ability to boot back into Windows any time you feel you need to.